# What aircraft model is on this old photograph?

Tags: aircraft-identification

I would be grateful if anyone could identify this - Copyright Real Photographs Co. No. 750

[image]

Comment: Hello Ken, can you give us more information about the photograph? where did you find it? Where was is taken? Maybe the year?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89432/discussion-on-question-by-ken-what-aircraft-model-is-on-this-old-photograph).

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately I have no other information. The card was in a group of disparate aircraft postcards.

Answer (score 10):

It's a Carden-Baynes Bee... A British plane built in the 30s...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carden-Baynes_Bee

Comment: This one was not easy, congrats!